# iPhone doesn't show specified 4-Inch launch image on iPhone 5 Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I specified an 4-Inch launch image in my target summary, but the iOS 6 4-Inch simulator shows the 3.5 Inch image when I launch the app.
Anyone an idea? Which additional information do you need?

Comment: how you set frame for image..?????????

Comment: did you test app on 3.5 inch and worked ?

Comment: how to launch the image using .xib ?

Comment: plz check my answer below again i have changed it.

Comment: would you add piece of code that render the image ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure yon name it as Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136)

Comment: check your iPhone simulator has 4 inch 
hardware > device > iphone (retina 4 inch )

Comment: Yes, the current device is used.

Comment: Check that the the `Default-568h@2x.png` is include in the target.

Answer (score 0):

It might be constrains issue from the .xib file , try the following link to change the auto-layout configuration  http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/

also the images of the iphone devices now are as the following:
To run the image on the iPhone 4 inch you have to add **-568h@2x** between the name and extension

ex:
MYimage-568h@2x.png

for 3.5 inch display just name the image :
MYimage@2x.png

and for normal iphone {3Gs or older }  just name the image :
MYimage.png

Answer (score 0):

Click on the image in xcode then right side u see the **Image Properties** check the Dimensions